# Xamarin Navigation Issue on Back

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I've three pages first showing List of my items on tap I'm redirecting it to a History Page with Object defined with  static property with

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"/{nameof(DeviceHistoryPage)}");
```

then from this page i'm again redirecting user to show more details of each history item to next page with data as static property

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"/{nameof(DeviceHistoryDetailsPage)}");
```

I'm able to achieve this navigation and able to move back and forth from first page to second page but from second page once redirected to third page and i'm not able return back to previous page with back button present in navbar

Also I've tried registering routes as independent as well as a child in AppShell as follows

```
Routing.RegisterRoute($"{nameof(ListPage)}/{nameof(HistoryPage)}", typeof(HistoryPage));
Routing.RegisterRoute($"{nameof(HistoryPage)}/{nameof(HistoryDetailsPage)}", typeof(HistoryDetailsPage));
```

Comment: what happens when you press the back nav button on the first page?  Nothing?  Are there errors or exceptions?  Is anything shown in the console?

Comment: Show the xaml starting with `<Shell`, and including ListPage, HistoryPage, and HistoryDetailsPage. Need to see how those are related to each other in the xaml. Also, what happens if you change second RegisterRoute to `$"{nameof(ListPage)}/{nameof(HistoryPage)}/{nameof(HistoryDetailsPage)}"`?

Comment: @Jason there are no errors on pressing the back nav button on the first page

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve actually List Page has list of all items, on tap of each item page redirected to HistoryPage which has three tabs and from one of tab i'm redirecting user to HistoryDetailsPage, this navigation happens perfectly but the issue is whenever user trying to get back to HistoryPage from details page it is getting confused with tabs. How can i deal with this?

Only HistoryPage has tabs elsewhere i'm using flyout for navigation.

Comment: * Are HistoryPage (or DeviceHistoryPage) and HistoryDetailsPage mentioned in `<ShellContent>`s? If they are, show the xaml that mentions them, starting from `<Shell>`. That may affect what is happening. * *"it is getting confused with tabs"*: I don't know what that means.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't wrapping your pages into a NavigationPage() and utilising the PushAsync / PopAsync methods?